# PHP System_Daemon cpu usage

Tags: php, daemon

I'm using System_Daemon to make a daemon by PHP. This daemon will look into a folder and monitor if there is a file with command inside then execute it. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

define('_WEB_DIR', dirname(__FILE__ ));
define('_DAEMON_CMD_FILE', dirname(__FILE__ ).'/daemon/cmd.sh');

// Include Class
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "System/Daemon.php";


$options = array(
        "appName" => "serverhandler",
        "appDir" => dirname(__FILE__),
        "appDescription" => "Runn commands to control web service ( httpd | nginx | lightpd ... )",
        "authorName" => "Jerry Pham",
        "authorEmail" => "author@email.com",
        "sysMaxExecutionTime" => "0",
        "sysMaxInputTime" => "0",
        "sysMemoryLimit" => "1024M"
);

System_Daemon::setOptions($options);

System_Daemon::start();

while (!System_Daemon::isDying()  )
{
    if( file_exists( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE ) )
    {
        $cmd = file_get_contents( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE );
        unlink( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE );
        $result = system( $cmd );
        System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_NOTICE, "Excuted command {$cmd} : {$result}");
    }
}

System_Daemon::stop();



?>
```

But after ~ 2hrs running, cpu usage is 80% and memory is 1.1%. Could anybody help me to explain this CPU issue and how to fix.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, Just put `usleep(1000); //0.1 second` in while loop:

```
 while (!System_Daemon::isDying()  )
{
    if( file_exists( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE ) )
    {
        $cmd = file_get_contents( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE );
        unlink( _DAEMON_CMD_FILE );
        $result = system( $cmd );
        System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_NOTICE, "Excuted command {$cmd} : {$result}");
    }
    usleep(1000);
}
```

I thought System_Daemon will do sleep for us but seem it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you can,you shuold use "System_Daemon::iterate()"

```
while (!System_Daemon::isDying())
    {
        //do something
        System_Daemon::iterate(1);    //sleep 1 sec and do clearstatcache()
    }
```